# Why can I not move bones in pose mode with mouse?

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes

I have frame 16 selected in the animation timeline, I am in pose mode trying to rotate a bone. Automatic keyframe insertion is selected, so when I rotate a bone the keyframe is created.

My problem is that the bone reverts to its initial position after I left click to confirm. If I change the values manually in the properties panel then it works, but that takes a long time. In the properties panel, the text areas for all the values are yellow instead of white.

In the tutorial I am watching he just rotates and clicks, and the keyframe is created with the correct new rotate values. I am doing the same thing and it won't work.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qb8mpy7x5vt4cvw/boneswontmove.blend?dl=0
There is a link to the .blend file in case anybody would take a minute to look at this, i'm sure any of you would instantly know what the problem is. Thanks

Edit:

[SOLVED]

Solution found on my thread [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?373618-Cannot-move-bones-in-pose-mode-with-mouse)

Simply select the armature, go into the object properties panel, and set the duplication to none.

Comment: It sounds like the person in the tutorial might have *auto key* enabled.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Maybe you enabled auto key only for location: the image shows the correct combination for inserting location, rotation and scale keyframes every time you move a bone in a frame.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everybody, I set it the same way with LocRot in that box and I still am unable to rotate. I can rotate if I manually type in the rotation values. It simply won't let me grab the bone, and rotate it with the mouse. In the video, he doesn't put anything in that box to the right where you put LocRotScale. But I will keep messing around and see I can get it to work. Thanks again for responding

Comment: Please send us your .blend file, so we can analize it and see what's the problem!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qb8mpy7x5vt4cvw/boneswontmove.blend?dl=0  Thanks, I assume you meant post it like that.